# Return value within promise then is always undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, return

I have a function that makes a database call. I want to return a boolean value if this operation is successful, but I always get `undefined`. As I've read the return value should be a promise as well, but if I want to `then/catch` the "promise" my function returns an `undefined`.

```
const foobar = function(data) {
    db.call(data).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res); // returns the expected data, e.g.["foobar", "foo", "bar"]
        return res.includes("bar");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // if an error occures, the function should ...
        // ... return a false value as well
        return false;
    });
};
```

My function call looks like this: `foobar({1: 'a'})`. How can I fetch the boolean return value in the correct way?
I've tried it with the following two options:

First I thought that the return value would be a normal boolean value:

```
const return_value = foorbar({1: 'a'}); // returns undefined
```

After I've read that the return value within a `then` function would be a promise as well, I've tried to `then/catch` it:

```
const return_value = foobar({1: 'a'}
).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res); 
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err); 
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

The output clearly indicates that the result is not a promise, it's just `undefined`. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the `foobar` function itself - just the calls to `.then` and `.catch`.

```
return db.call(data).then(...).catch(...);
```

You could also change `foobar` to an ES6 arrow function and take advantage of the implicit return:

```
const foobar = data => db.call(data).then(...).catch(...);
```

Note that ES6 functions won't be accessible before they're defined if you use `const` or `let` - so make sure if you're using arrow functions, they're all defined in one area at the top. ES5 functions have no such restriction because they are all located before any of the code runs.

Comment: Thanks, I was clearly blind. Are there any other ways to receive such return values? Or any better ways?

Comment: Unless you use an ES6 arrow function's implicit return feature, you need to do it this way. I'll update my answer with that approach.